# Hibernate Validator not invoked on Object Graph

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bean-validation

I have a model object which has entities annotated with hibernate validation annotations. For example @NotBlank, @NotNull, @Length.
I have a form backing this model which decorates an instance of the model object. I have annotated this instance with an @NotNull, @Valid annotation. I am registering a validator for this backing form in the Controller Class and the form validator is being invoked when the @RequestMapping method argument is annotated with @Valid annotation.

Note the model is also annotated with the @Entity annotation, the model backing form is just 
a thin wrapper around the model.

However the validations on the decorated object are not being checked? I know this because in the request mapping method definition I check the BindResult for errors and there are none.
My form fields are all empty, hence the validations on the fields on the decorated model annotated with @NotBlank should be checked. However that does not happen.

Can you help me fix this?

Edit:
Sample Code

```
@Entity
class MyModel {
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique=true, length=30, nullable=false)
    private String number;

    @Column(length=30, nullable=false)
    @Length(min=1, max=30)
private String firstName;
    /* ... getters and setters ... */
}

public class MyModelBackingForm {

   @NotNull
   @Valid
   private MyModel model;
   /* ... delegate getters and setters for all fields in MyModel ...  */
 }
```

Edit:
Add Controller Code

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.setValidator(new MyBackingFormValidator());
}
```

Edit:

```
public class MyBackingFormValidator implements Validator {

  public MyBackingFormValidator() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Arrays.asList(MyBackingForm.class, MyModel.class).contains(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
   // custom validation code commented ... as I want to check if JSR 303 validations invoked
  }
}
```

Comment: Could it because I am using a decorator, the fields in the model class are not being validated?

Comment: Could you attach your pojo and controller here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code the way I was using the hibernate validation. I was calling @valid on the fetched objects with the binding result. This way it knows the validations which are required to be done on the form. 
Edited: How to invoke custom and standard validator?

Using @InitBinder we can pass the custom validator instance to which again we can pass the class parameter for the standard validator using binder.getValidator()

Courtesy: Rohit Banga

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
```

//Edited:

```
@InitBinder 
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) { 
binder.setValidator(new CustomFormValidator(binder.getValidator())); 
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCustomer(@Valid Customer customer, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "form";
        } else {
            return "success";
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String customerForm(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "form";

    }

}
```

Comment: This code works assuming you have initBinder method.
But I am wrapping the Customer object in a CustomerForm object and I suspect the delegate methods are causing problems. Hibernate supports object graph Validations, so I am not sure why it is not working.
I am using a separate form because of the suggestions here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1852549/161628

Comment: And did you try calling the form object in the controller with the @valid annotation?

Comment: Yes I did use the @Valid annotation on the form parameter of the RequestMapping annotated method.

Comment: Found the problem ... I have shown the controller code as well in the example. If I comment out the initBinder method, the validators are invoked on the decorated model.

Comment: So I guess now the problem is how to use both the default validator along with my custom one.

Comment: I see...Its a desired behavior to override the standard validator with the custom one but since, you are checking for the hibernate validation in form object it shouldn't have been the problem in the first place. Could attach your custom validator as well

Comment: Added more code ... I want to use both validations - based on annotations and custom validations.

Comment: Also tried using SpringValidatorAdapter with LocalValidatorFactoryBean() getting a Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Fixed it:
Use the following init Binder Method:
`  @InitBinder
  protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new MyBackingFormValidator(binder.getValidator()));
  }`
Store the constructor parameter as a class parameter and invoke validator.validate(obj, errors); in MyBackingFormValidator.validate() method.

Comment: If you can include this information in your answer, I will accept it